# EF core fetch string as enum type

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm running a large `SELECT` with ordes of magnitude of 100.000 rows on an MYSQL database.
The table i'm fetching has a column called `type` which has 4 different string values.

```
|Id|Type  |MetaKey|MetaValue|
|===========================|
|01|'line'|'AKey' |AValue   |
|02|'line'|'AKey1'|AValue   |
|03|'Ship'|'AKey2'|AValue   |
|04|'Fee' |'AKey3'|AValue   |
|05|'Ship'|'AKey4'|AValue   |
```

Currently the main bottleneck seems to be network transit so optimally i'd like to cast these 4 different string values to an int enum (or something small) so that i save memory for transit.

I gues MYSQL `CASE` would allow to do this in SQL.

Is this possible with EF core? What would the LINQ syntax look like?

To reiterate - i want the conversion to done in the database, not in the C# client.

EDIT: Apologies - i got confused, this is an MYSQL database not an MSSQL database.

Comment: Why not have an int column in the first place?

Comment: @Fildor good question - but this is not my database, i'm only pulling data from it. I have no say in how the database looks.

Comment: EF core has this feature called "value conversions". It does the conversion client-side, but it'd be a very convenient solution.

Comment: @GertArnold Yeah i figured as  much. This is mostly about perf though.

Comment: @sommmen performance isn't affected by the value conversion. You need to parse that string into an enum anyway

Comment: @sommmen what you ask is already available out of the box. Check [Pre-defined conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#pre-defined-conversions). All you need to do is annotate the `Type` property

Comment: @sommmen if you want to reduce the network bandwidth you *MUST* use integers instead of strings. EF Core doesn't change how the database works, it maps the results to objects. 100K rows isn't a lot of data. You could enable compression on the connection and probably get better performance at least for this query. *Maybe* you could create a LINQ SELECT that would map to a `CASE WHEN 'line'  THEN 1`. Or perhaps you could create a computed column in the table to perform the mapping instead of trying to approximate the `CASE` in LINQ

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the information you've provided. i'll go check some links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should looks like this:

```cs
public enum MyEnum
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Line = 1,
    Ship = 2,
    Fee = 3
}
```

```cs
var query = 
    from t in ctx.Table
    select new 
    {
        c.Id,
        c.MetaKey,
        c.MetaValue,
        Type = (MyEnum)(
            c.Type == "line" ? 1 :
            c.Type == "Ship" ? 2 :
            c.Type == "Fee" ? 3 : 0)
    };
```

EF Core generates optimal expression for returning integer:

```sql
CAST(CASE
    WHEN [e].[Type] = N'line' THEN 1
    WHEN [e].[Type] = N'Ship' THEN 2
    WHEN [e].[Type] = N'Fee' THEN 3
    ELSE 0
END AS int)
```

Comment: Hm that seems easy enough - ill see if that gets translated to SQL rather than being evaluated client side in a second.

Comment: There's no reason for such code at all. This would litter every single query with conversions. EF Core already handles this scenario with value converters. Besides, even that deeply nested comparison isn't needed - `Enum.Parse` would do the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, What do you mean litter?  Do you read original question? How to reduce payload?

Comment: First, string to enum conversions are already available. Even if that wasn't the case, you can parse a string to an enum with `Enum.Parse` or `Enum.TryParse`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, strings will be transferred to the client - this is what OP want to omit. Read question again.

Comment: Why do you assume your code *won't* be evaluated on the client? Or that EF Core won't simply choke trying to convert that nested if to SQL? Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes! Tested on EF Core 5.

Comment: And? What was the generated MySQL query? It's not enough to run the LINQ query, the SQL query itself must return an integer.

Comment: ` CAST(CASE
          WHEN [e].[Type] = N'line' THEN 1
          WHEN [e].[Type] = N'Ship' THEN 2
          WHEN [e].[Type] = N'Fee' THEN 3
          ELSE 0
      END AS int)`

Comment: Post that in the answer itself